# Is there a way to determine what specific physical USB port a device is connected to in macOS?

Tags: macos, usb

I have a Nexus 7 tablet attached to a Mac Mini, and I need to figure out what port it is connected to. I am managing someone else’s code, in which they litearally define the port:

```
/dev/tty.usbserial-A20e1sNr
```

This port has now changed, and there seem to be about 20 different USB devices hooked up to this computer. Is there a way to figure out what specific port corresponds to the USB port the Nexus 7 tablet is connected to?

Answer (score 0):

`/dev/tty.usbserial` is USB to serial connection, so other USB devices doesn't show up here. I would recommend listing all `usb.serial` devices using:

```
ls -la /dev/tty.usbserial*
```

If there is more than one, disconnect Nexus tablet and list USB connected devices again and check which one disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

You can use `ioreg -p IOUSB` to see the USB tree is it is registered with the IOKit (or use the *System Information* app, under Hardware/USB).

Additionally, `ioreg -l -p IOUSB` prints properties, among these `USB Address` (which seems to be the port number of the parent hub), and `locationID`, which according to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iokit/iousbdeviceinterface/1559284-getlocationid?language=objc) is a

> 32 bit number which is unique among all USB devices in the system, and which will not change on a system reboot unless the topology of the bus itself changes.

The value returned by [IORegistryEntryGetLocationInPlane](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iokit/1514340-ioregistryentrygetlocationinplan?language=objc), which is displayed after the `@` in the `ioreg` output, also seems to contain some sort of port path, or at least a unique identifier.

I don't have USB serial devices to play around with here, so I don't know how this information is related to the identifier after `tty.usbserial`, or if you can obtain this identifier with `iokit` in another way.